# Binomial theorem and a congruence modulo $2^{2m+2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, binomial-theorem, quadratic-residues

I'm interested in the congruence problem $$(1 + 2^m)^{2x} \equiv 1+ 2^{m+1} \pmod{2^{2m+2}}\,,\quad m \geq 2\,.\quad(\dagger)$$

Though I can solve it for various small values of $m$, I still haven't found a proof that a solution exists for every such $m$.

For context, I'm reading a paper and thinking about the possibilities of extending its results. The author himself claims that extending the theorem in a certain direction is trivial, and part of this is because he claims that $(\dagger)$ always has a solution for each $m \geq 2$.

I have tried so far to expand $(1 + 2^m)^{2x}$ using the binomial theorem and reducing the problem to the quadratic equation $$2^mx^2 + (1-2^{m-1})x-1\equiv 0 \pmod{2^{m+1}}\,,\quad m\geq 2\,.\quad (\ddagger)$$ but that didn't helped much either.

> I'm looking for hints to prove that $(\dagger)$ or equivalently $(\ddagger)$ aways has a solution $x$ for every such value of $m$.

Comment: Your reduction to the quadratic equation will work, just keep going. First reduce the equation $\bmod 2^{m-1}$; what do you conclude about $x$? Then reduce it $\bmod 2^{m+1}$ and see what more you can conclude.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thanks! With your tip I've managed to not only prove that the reduction has a solution, but also to find it explicitly $\mod{2^{m+1}}$. An extra reduction $\mod{2^m}$ also helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we choose $x$ such that
$$
(1-2^{m-1})x\equiv 1+2^m\;(\text{mod}\;2^{m+1})
$$
then $2^mx^2$ and $(1-2^{m-1})x-1$ are both odd multiples of $2^m$, hence
$$
2^mx^2 + \bigl((1-2^{m-1})x-1\bigr)
$$
is a multiple of $2^{m+1}$.

Comment: The answer gives the idea for a very simple proof of the existence of such $x$, which is all I needed. Combining this with @QiaochuYuan's suggestion of also reducing it modulo $2^{m-1}$ and $2^m$ also gives an explicit value for $x$ in an even easier way than the quadratic reduction, which is a bonus!